# Is code "if sql_answer: " in pythonic style

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a junior and in my pet project wrote next code:

```
# Try to find information about this offer in database
sql_answer_ad = __select_from_ad_table(conn, cur, (one_offer_data[0],))

# If information about offer is in database                
if sql_answer_ad:
```

But some of my friends think that right variant is

```
if __is_sql_answer_ad_not_empty():
```

What you think, what variant is more pythonic?

`if sql_answer_ad:`, IMHO, standard code construction. I saw same code many times.
I.e.:

1. finally block in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sqlite-connecting-to-database/
2. Naomi CEDER. "The Quick Python Book"

Comment: What does `__select_from_ad_table()` return?

Comment: Sorry. M.b. it needed to add in question. __select_from_ad_table() send a request to database (SELECT FROM) and use fetchone().  Returned tuple or None

Comment: Your code is fine, except for the ugly names. E.g. simpler `select_from_ad_table` and `sql_answer` would be better.

Comment: @zvone double underline used because this function is private and 'sql_answer_ad' used because below the code used 'sql_answer' from other tables of database. But thank you for comment

Comment: As you wish. Still, private functions should start with a single underline, not double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one is smaller, and has everything you need to know,

```py
if sql_answer_ad:
```

anyone with at least a week of experience in python will know that the first code variation is checking that the reply is not empty, and very long names that add nothing to context are bad, as they reduce the white space, which makes reading the code harder.

i know you are checking that the reply is not empty, if you put a 10 word function in front of my face i will have to read its name and figure out what it is doing instead of skipping it, which reduces code readability.

as to what is pythonic, if you look into [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) you will find

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't think about [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Comment: @Vladimir if this answers your question you can pick the "mark as correct answer" sign to the left of the answer.